# display a 'view' list within a composite layout in drupal

Tags: drupal, layout, module, composite

I've installed the composite layout module and I created a view with a list of 'testomonials'(just a simple list of title and excerpt).

On my front page, I have been able to include a couple of other nodes within that page and a couple of blocks (e.g. within then same composite layout).  However, I want to also include the list view of the testimonials (I want to display the whole list and then use javascript to manipulate it).

So my question is, is it possible to include a view list inside a composite layout and if not how would I take my front drupal page and include a node AND say my list of testimonials

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Instead of this use http://drupal.org/project/panels. 
Also you can use modules like http://drupal.org/project/views and http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs. p.s. Power, flexible and faster way - manually drawing html page with css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a views module view, you can turn that into a block by adding a display of type block to it (on the views configuration page). Once you saved that, it will be available as any other block on the blocks configuration page.

Comment: how do I add more block areas. For example on the front page, I want a welcome-text area, a testimonials area, and then an area for current events. So could I make a front page template with 'block' areas for these content items?

Thanks

andy

Comment: If by 'block areas' you mean the places where you can assign blocks to, they are called 'regions' in the Drupal context. Read up on theming add more: http://drupal.org/node/171224 and http://drupal.org/node/337173